# How to create a dynamic unique constraint

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a huge table that is partitioned by a partition id. Each partition can have a different number of fields in its unique constraint. Consider this table:

```
+----+---------+-------+-----+--+
| id | part_id | name  | age |  |
+----+---------+-------+-----+--+
| 1  | 1       | James | 12  |  |
+----+---------+-------+-----+--+
| 2  | 1       | Mary  | 33  |  |
+----+---------+-------+-----+--+
| 3  | 2       | James | 1   |  |
+----+---------+-------+-----+--+
| 4  | 2       | Mike  | 19  |  |
+----+---------+-------+-----+--+
| 5  | 3       | James | 12  |  |
+----+---------+-------+-----+--+
```

For `part_id: 1` I need a unique constraint on fields `name and age`. `part_id: 2` needs a unique constraint on `name`. `part_id: 3` needs a unique constraint on `name`. I am open to any database that can accomplish this.

Comment: You flagged multiple SQL servers each with their own dialects and ways of doing partitions. Could you narrow it down to the one you're actually using? Also, could you give some more detail about why these different parts need different constraints? It might be better to remodel your data.

Comment: @Schwern I am open to any RDBMS that can accomplish this.

Comment: So your schema has not been set yet? You'll get better answers if you back up and say more about what problem you're trying to solve with partitions (see [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140334)).

Comment: My current schema is in sql server but I am willing to switch databases. I can't find an efficient solution in sql server. The schema in the question is a watered down version of my real table. I'll try to explain the question further.

Comment: What are the rules that determine which columns need to be unique for which part?

Comment: There are no rules. They are user defined.

Answer (score 1):

Classic RDBMS is designed to work with stable schema. It means that the structure of your tables, columns, indexes, relations don't change often, each table has a fixed number of columns with fixed types and it is hard/inefficient to make them dynamic.

SQL Server has [filtered indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx).

So, you can create a separate unique index for each partition.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Part1 ON YourTable
(
    name ASC,
    age ASC
)
WHERE (part_id = 1)


CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Part2 ON YourTable
(
    name ASC
)
WHERE (part_id = 2)


CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Part3 ON YourTable
(
    name ASC
)
WHERE (part_id = 3)
```

These DDL statements are static and the value of `part_id` is hard coded in them. Optimiser is able to use such indexes in queries that have the same `WHERE` filter, so they are useful not just for enforcing the constraint.

You can always write a procedure that would generate a text of the `CREATE INDEX` statement dynamically and run it via `EXEC`/`sp_executesql`. There may be some clever use of triggers on `YourTable` to create it on the fly as the data in your table changes, but in the end it will be some static `CREATE INDEX` statement.

You can create these indexes in advance for all possible values of `part_id`, even if there are no such actual values in the table yet.

---

If you have thousands of `part_id` and you want to create thousands of such unique constraints, then your current schema may not be quite appropriate.

SQL Server allows max 999 nonclustered indexes per table. See [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx).

Are you trying to build some variation of [EAV (entity-attribute-value) model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)?

Maybe there are non-relational DBMS that allow greater flexibility that would suit better for your task, but I don't have experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, the below is possible to create unique index dynamically

```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_part_id_dynamic ON partition_table part_id,
    (CASE WHEN part_id = 1 THEN name, age
          WHEN part_id = 3 THEN age
          ELSE height
    END );
    );
```

Comment: Good suggestion, is it possible to do this without speciying the part_id. I will have thousands of part_ids.

Comment: Yes, You can just move the part_id inside the "THEN" of each Case condition.